# Restoring in app purchase observer calls addPayment instead of restore

Tags: ios, swift, in-app-purchase

When restoring an in app purchase on ANOTHER device, restore  calls Purchase rather than Restore

- Button is hooked up correctly
- If a purchase has been pressed previously (even if canceled) this fixes the issue, even if the app has gone in to background.
- Only present when restoring purchase on another device
- Auto renewing subscription

Purchase pressed

```
SKPaymentQueue.defaultQueue().addTransactionObserver(self)
SKPaymentQueue.defaultQueue().addPayment(pay as SKPayment)
```

Storekit

```
func paymentQueue(queue: SKPaymentQueue!, updatedTransactions transactions: [AnyObject]!) {
    println("Purchasing")
```

Restore pressed

```
SKPaymentQueue.defaultQueue().addTransactionObserver(self)
SKPaymentQueue.defaultQueue().restoreCompletedTransactions()
```

Storekit should call

```
func paymentQueueRestoreCompletedTransactionsFinished(queue: SKPaymentQueue!) {
    println("transactions restored")
```

Actually calls (on another device if a purchase hasn't been tapped previously)

```
func paymentQueue(queue: SKPaymentQueue!, updatedTransactions transactions: [AnyObject]!) {
    println("Purchasing")
```

**UPDATE**

Adding

```
dispatch_after(dispatchTime, dispatch_get_main_queue(), {

             SKPaymentQueue.defaultQueue().addTransactionObserver(self)

        })

            SKPaymentQueue.defaultQueue().restoreCompletedTransactions()
```

To the Restore pressed fixes it most of the time, could do with a more permanent solution

Answer (score 0):

You should set the transaction observer asap (when the  `application:didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:` is called), not while handling the restore button tap. According to the [documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/tvos/documentation/StoreKit/Reference/SKPaymentQueue_Class/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/SKPaymentQueue/addTransactionObserver:):

> Your application should add an observer to the payment queue during application initialization. If there are no observers attached to the queue, the payment queue does not synchronize its list of pending transactions with the Apple App Store, because there is no observer to respond to updated transactions.